# Method, returning multiple values of different data types

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to return a string array `stringArray` of regex matches along with the associated match `match_count` `string_index` and `match_length`. How do I send multiple different values of different data types in the method return. I have read about a [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) But all the examples basically show multiple values but they always seem to be integers and not mixed types. I can't work out how to implement the string array and integers in my example using it.

```
    string ptrn_coords = @"- Coordinates: \[ ([\-0-9]+), ([\-0-9]+), ([\-0-9]+) \]";

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] matches;
        matches = GetMatches(s, ptrn_coords);
    }



    private static string[] GetMatches(string input, string pattern)
    {

        string[] stringArray;
        Match mc = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

        int string_index = 0;
        int match_length = 0;
        int match_count = 0;
        List<String> listTemp = new List<string>();
        while (mc.Success)
        {
            match_count++;
            string_index = mc.Index;
            match_length = mc.Length;               
            listTemp.Add(mc.ToString());

            //MessageBox.Show("Match Text: " + mc.ToString() + " Index: " + string_index + " Length: " + match_length + " Count: " + match_count); // Test Message

            mc = mc.NextMatch();
        }
        stringArray = listTemp.ToArray<String>();
        return stringArray;

    }
```

Comment: Really can't understand the down vote. It seems like a clear question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples are type safe, and can safely return mixes of primitive and complex types. Here's an example:

```
void Main()
{
    var x = GetTuple();
    Console.WriteLine($"{x.Item1} {x.Item2} {x.Item3.GetType().Name}"); // Prints "string 5 MyClass"
}

....

public Tuple<string, int, MyClass> GetTuple()
{
    string myString = "string";
    int myInt = 5;
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    return Tuple.Create(myString,myInt,myClass);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Retrieving the returned value is where it always seemed to break. This made it very concise. Thanks helped a lot.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad it helped. Be sure to mark one of the answers as accepted if it satisfies your question to help others in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want to return, if you want to return the stringarray and the matchcount etc. you can simply define a class with these properties then return an instance of this class.